# Why the Slider au scroll and its distortion effect created with Three.js and Parcel.js doesn't appear any more？

Tags: three.js, gsap, parceljs, barbajs

I have 2 pages and page 2 contains a horizontal scrolling slider with a distortion effect created with Three.js and Parcel.js (+ cursor effect with gsap on those 2 pages).
Separately, 2 pages work very well using **parcel ***.html** to show pages on the browser.

**Problem:** After adding a page transition effect with barbar.js and gsap, every time I go to the page 2 from page 1, the page transition works perfectly, but **neither the slider nor the distortion effect with Three.js appear**. I have to refresh page 2 to see the slider with the distortion effect.

In my project folder, I have 2 HTML files and 3 JavaScript files (app.js for the page transition, cursor.js for the cursor effect & page2.js for the scrolling slider with distortion effect). I don't know where is the problem. Maybe I need some codes to connect these JS files? Or is it the problem related to Parcel.js?

I paste my code below. Could you help me with that? Thank you in advance...

Info: I've installed three.js, parcel.js, and gsap with npm.

Page1.html:

```
<body data-barba="wrapper">
    <div class="cont-bandes">
        <div class="bande"></div>
        <div class="bande"></div>
        <div class="bande"></div>
        <div class="bande"></div>
        <div class="bande"></div>
        <div class="bande"></div>
        <div class="bande"></div>
        <div class="bande"></div>
        <div class="bande"></div>
        <div class="bande"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wipe-transition"></div>

    <div class="cursor">
        <div class="cursor__ball cursor__ball--big">
            <svg height="30" width="30">
                <circle cx="15" cy="15" r="12" stroke-width="0"></circle>
            </svg>
        </div>

        <div class="cursor__ball cursor__ball--small">
            <svg height="10" width="10">
                <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke-width="0"></circle>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>

    <main data-barba="container" data-barba-namespace="home">

        <h1 class="homeTitle">Japan</h1>

    </main>

    <footer>

        <nav class="pagesNav">
            <ul class="pagesNav__items">
                <li>
                    <a href="./index.html" class="hoverable">
                        <span class="letter">H</span>
                        <span class="letter">o</span>
                        <span class="letter">m</span>
                        <span class="letter">e</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="./osaka.html" class="hoverable">
                        <span class="letter">O</span>
                        <span class="letter">s</span>
                        <span class="letter">a</span>
                        <span class="letter">k</span>
                        <span class="letter">a</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="hoverable">
                        <span class="letter">T</span>
                        <span class="letter">o</span>
                        <span class="letter">k</span>
                        <span class="letter">y</span>
                        <span class="letter">o</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="hoverable">
                        <span class="letter">K</span>
                        <span class="letter">y</span>
                        <span class="letter">o</span>
                        <span class="letter">t</span>
                        <span class="letter">o</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </footer>

    <script src="/scripts/cursor.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@barba/core"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/app.js"></script>


</body>
```

Page2.html:

```
<body class="osaka-body" data-barba="wrapper">

    <div class="transition">
        <div class="bande"></div>
        <div class="bande"></div>
        <div class="bande"></div>
        <div class="bande"></div>
        <div class="bande"></div>
        <div class="bande"></div>
        <div class="bande"></div>
        <div class="bande"></div>
        <div class="bande"></div>
        <div class="bande"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="cursor">
        <div class="cursor__ball cursor__ball--big">
            <svg height="30" width="30">
                <circle cx="15" cy="15" r="12" stroke-width="0"></circle>
            </svg>
        </div>

        <div class="cursor__ball cursor__ball--small">
            <svg height="10" width="10">
                <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke-width="0"></circle>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>

    <main data-barba="container" data-barba-namespace="home">
        <header>
            <h1 class="osakaTitle">大阪</span></h1>
        </header>

        <div class="slider">
            <div class="slider-inner">
                <div class="item hoverable">
                    <img src="images/osaka/1.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="item hoverable">
                    <img src="images/osaka/2.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="item hoverable">
                    <img src="images/osaka/3.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="item hoverable">
                    <img src="images/osaka/4.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="item hoverable">
                    <img src="images/osaka/5.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="item hoverable">
                    <img src="images/osaka/6.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </main>

    <footer>

        <nav class="pagesNav">
            <ul class="pagesNav__items">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html" class="hoverable">
                        <span class="letter">H</span>
                        <span class="letter">o</span>
                        <span class="letter">m</span>
                        <span class="letter">e</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="osaka.html" class="hoverable">
                        <span class="letter">O</span>
                        <span class="letter">s</span>
                        <span class="letter">a</span>
                        <span class="letter">k</span>
                        <span class="letter">a</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="hoverable">
                        <span class="letter">T</span>
                        <span class="letter">o</span>
                        <span class="letter">k</span>
                        <span class="letter">y</span>
                        <span class="letter">o</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="hoverable">
                        <span class="letter">K</span>
                        <span class="letter">y</span>
                        <span class="letter">o</span>
                        <span class="letter">t</span>
                        <span class="letter">o</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </footer>

    <script src="scripts/slider.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/cursor.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@barba/core"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/app.js"></script>

</body>
```

app.js:

```
import gsap from "gsap";

const wipe = document.querySelector('.wipe-transition');
const allBandes = document.querySelectorAll('.bande');
const TLAnim = gsap.timeline();

function delay(n) {
    return new Promise((done) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            done();
        }, n)
    })
}

barba.init({

    sync: true,

    transitions: [
        {
            async leave() {

                const done = this.async();

                TLAnim
                    .to(allBandes, { height: '100%', stagger: 0.05 })


                await delay(1500);
                done();

            },
            enter() {


                TLAnim
                    .to(allBandes, { height: '0%', stagger: 0.05 })

            }
        }
    ]

})
```

slider.js:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import vertexShader from './shaders/vertexShader.glsl';
import fragmentShader from './shaders/fragmentShader.glsl';


const images = [...document.querySelectorAll('img')];
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
let sliderWidth;
let imageWidth;
let current = 0;
let target = 0;
const ease = .05;


function lerp(start, end, t) {
    return start * (1 - t) + end * t;
}

function setTransform(el, transform) {
    el.style.transform = transform;
}

function init() {
    sliderWidth = slider.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    imageWidth = sliderWidth / images.length;
    document.body.style.height = `${sliderWidth - (window.innerWidth - window.innerHeight)}px`;
}


function animate() {
    current = parseFloat(lerp(current, target, ease)).toFixed(2);
    target = window.scrollY;
    slider.style.transform = `translate3d(${-current}px, 0, 0)`
}

class EffectCanvas {
    constructor() {
        this.container = document.querySelector('main');
        this.width = this.container.offsetWidth;
        this.height = this.container.offsetHeight;

        this.images = [...document.querySelectorAll('img')];


        this.meshItems = []; // Used to store all meshes we will be creating.
        this.setupCamera();
        this.createMeshItems();
        this.render();
    }

    // Getter function used to get screen dimensions used for the camera and mesh materials
    get viewport() {
        let width = window.innerWidth;
        let height = window.innerHeight;
        let aspectRatio = width / height;
        return {
            width,
            height,
            aspectRatio
        };
    }

    setupCamera() {
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.resize.bind(this));

        // Create new scene
        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

        // Initialize perspective camera
        let perspective = 1000;
        const fov = (180 * (2 * Math.atan(window.innerHeight / 2 / perspective))) / Math.PI; 
        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, this.viewport.aspectRatio, 1, 1000);
        this.camera.position.set(0, 0, perspective) 

        //renderer
        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            antialias: true,
            alpha: true
        });
        this.renderer.setSize(this.viewport.width, this.viewport.height); 
        this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio); 
        this.container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement); 
    }

    resize() {
        init();
        this.camera.aspect = this.viewport.aspectRatio; 
        this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix(); 
        this.renderer.setSize(this.viewport.width, this.viewport.height);
    }

    createMeshItems() {
        this.images.forEach(image => {
            let meshItem = new MeshItem(image, this.scene);
            this.meshItems.push(meshItem);
        });
    }

    render() {
        animate();
        for (let i = 0; i < this.meshItems.length; i++) {
            this.meshItems[i].render();
        }
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
        requestAnimationFrame(this.render.bind(this));
    }

}

class MeshItem {
    constructor(element, scene) {
        this.element = element;
        this.scene = scene;
        this.offset = new THREE.Vector2(0, 0);
        this.sizes = new THREE.Vector2(0, 0);
        this.createMesh();

        console.log(this.element);
    }



    getDimensions() {
        const { width, height, top, left } = this.element.getBoundingClientRect();
        this.sizes.set(width, height);
        this.container = document.querySelector('main');
        this.width = this.container.offsetWidth;
        this.height = this.container.offsetHeight;
        this.offset.set(left - this.width / 2 + width / 2., -top + this.height / 2 - height / 2.); 
    }

    createMesh() {
        this.geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1, 30, 30); 

        this.imageTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(this.element.src);
        console.log(this.imageTexture);

        this.uniforms = {
            uTexture: { value: this.imageTexture },
            uOffset: { value: new THREE.Vector2(0, 0) },
            uAlpha: { value: 1.0 } 
        }
        this.material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
            uniforms: this.uniforms,
            vertexShader: vertexShader,
            fragmentShader: fragmentShader
        });
        this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(this.geometry, this.material);
        this.getDimensions();
        this.mesh.position.set(this.offset.x, this.offset.y, 0);
        this.mesh.scale.set(this.sizes.x, this.sizes.y, 1);

        this.scene.add(this.mesh);
    }

    render() {
        this.getDimensions();
        this.mesh.position.set(this.offset.x, this.offset.y, 0);
        this.mesh.scale.set(this.sizes.x, this.sizes.y, 0);
        this.uniforms.uOffset.value.set(-(target - current) * 0.0002, 0.0); 
    }
}

init();
new EffectCanvas();
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Anyone can help me with this problem? Is it about barba.js? Need another function to reload other js files after page transition?

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue with barba.js and gsap animations, only worked in the first page, after transition every other animation in my main.js doens't worked.

In the documentation I found a solution to make it work called `view`

[Barba.js documentation - view](https://barba.js.org/docs/advanced/views/)

Exemple:

```js
barba.init({
  views: [{
    namespace: 'page1',
    beforeLeave(data) {
      // do something before leaving the current `page1` namespace
      // it's not what you looking for, but it is good to know
    }
  }, {
    namespace: 'page2',
    beforeEnter(data) {
      // (here it's what you want) do something before entering the `page2` namespace
      // your animation here
      function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
        cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
      }

      animate();
    }
  }]
});
```

The thing is, javascript need to run in every page to work, since barba.js only refresh the content, you need to run your javascript again.
With `view` you can run your javascript properly in every different page, and even distribute it properly between pages.